# Array element returning "true" instead of value

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP code that converts a JSON into an array of two elements.

```
{"object":"card","id":"card_1"}
```

But when I try to print the both, the first returns the value and the second only the boolean.

```
echo 'id = ' . $response["id"];
echo 'object = ' .$response["object"];
```

Getting this:

```
id = true
object = card
```

What is wrong?

Comment: How did you convert json into array? Can you show the code?

Comment: write the code you use to convert json to array

Comment: can't reproduce   http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b8bc0b2a2231e1a9810db581196c210a58f2fa0

Comment: write the output of this var_dump($response);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you use `json_decode` to convert your `JSON` data to an array. Use next basic example to get your expected data:

```
<?php
// Input
$json = '{"object":"card","id":"card_1"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);

// Specific items
echo 'id = '.$array["id"].'<br>';
echo 'object = '.$array["object"].'<br>';

// All items
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   echo $key.": ".$value."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide the code you use to convert this JSON into an array ?

This works fine:

```php
$jsonObject = '{"object":"card","id":"card_1"}';

$decodedObject = json_decode($jsonObject);

$object = $decodedObject->object;
$id = $decodedObject->id;

echo "Object: {$object}, ID: {$id}";
```